# How to join N datasets with common headers?

Tags: dataset, data-structures

I am new to `Dataset`. I'm trying to join many datasets, naively trying to use `Join`, but I think I'm not using it correctly, or perhaps that's not the right approach.

Example:

`listdatasets = {dataset1, dataset2, dataset3, ... , datasetN}`

If I do:

`Join[listdatasets]` that gives again a list of N datasets again (no difference from `listdatasets` list).

Manually, I can do:

`Join[listdatasets[[1]], listdatasets[[2]], ... , listdatasets[[N]]]`, but of course this is not ideal. Creating a Table inside join does not work (for instance `Join[Table[listdatasets[[a]], {1,Length[listdatasets]}]`)

All datasets have the same headers, so no need to do anything else but join them. I cannot find this seemingly trivial answer, so I'd appreciate your help :).

Thanks!

Pedro

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
Join @@ {dataset1,dataset2, dataset3}
```

See [Apply (@@)](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Apply.html)  in the docs.